# Rational or Irrational?

Tags: exponential-function, irrational-numbers, pi

Here is my question: can an Irrational number; like $e$, be equal to a second irrational number, $\pi$, times an integer, then divided by a second rational number?
Such as:
$e = \frac{\pi a }{b} $ , where $a$ and $b$ are some integers.
If not, can you explain why and include a proof? 
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Would you be able to explain what you think and what you have tried so far.

Comment: This is not clear.  Of course such a relation exists between some irrationals.  If $\alpha = \frac {\pi}2$ then $\alpha = \pi \times \frac 12$, say. It is unknown whether such a relation holds between $\pi$ and $e$ though presumably it does not.

Comment: Your example is with transcendental numbers. Maybe you are not asking the right question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x,y$ be irrational numbers, and $a,b$ be some integers different from $0$. Consider:
$$ \frac{x}{y}=\frac{a}{b} $$
which is clearly equivalent to your question. If $ \frac{x}{y}$ is rational, then the answer is yes, you can find some integers $a,b$ as above; otherwise, the answer is no. For instance, let $x=\sqrt{2}$, $y=3\sqrt{2}$. Then, you can write:
$$ x= \frac{1}{3} y $$
Regarding your particular case, namely $\frac{e}{\pi}$, I think it is not yet known whether this number is irrational or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

$$\sqrt8=2\sqrt2.$$

---

More generally, any irrational times a rational gives another irrational.

Answer (score 0):

An irrational number (called $a$) times rational number (called $b$) always gives a irrational number, except when $b=0$. Similar to the answer above (More generally, any irrational times a rational gives another irrational).

Now, irrational multiplied by irrational can give a rational (example $xy$ where $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $y=2\sqrt{2}$). But an irrational multiplied by a irrational can also give a irrational (such as if $r=\sqrt{2}$ and $d=\sqrt{5}$) then $rd$ is irrational. So a irrational number multiplied by irrational number is undetermined.

Regarding $\pi$ and $e$, I don't know the answer although this may be related to the topic of transcendental numbers as someone else has said above.